# Is there a way to calculate Cost Performance Index (CPI) without the actual $$ amount?

Tags: project-management, coding-efficiency, kpi

**Ask:** Looking for a way to calculate CPI KPIs for a program increment without the $$ amount.

GFG provides a very good explanation of CPI and SPI efficiency KPIs here - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-cost-performance-index-cpi-and-schedule-performance-index-spi/

"Cost Performance Index (CPI) is the measure of the cost efficiency of project. It is expressed as a ratio of earned value to actual cost"

Our scrum teams work in Agile and have estimated story points and velocity. So, I can easily calculate SPI scores for a sprint or program increment (PI) which is

```
SPI for a PI for a team = Story points accepted / Story points planned
```

We do not track "time spent" on a US or deal with actual $$ values for the PI (which I would presume most software teams do?)

For CPI, I am trying to figure out, with the data that is available to me from the tooling - which is velocity, accepted story points and the story points planned, is there any way for me to calculate CPI?

```
Cost Performance Index per PI = Story points accepted / Actual Cost
```

Is there a way I could use some other data points, such as user stories for the "actual costs" ? Apologies for the silly question in advance, but I dont seem to quite get CPI